# Storing time in array

Tags: php, arrays, time

I have some code that stores values in an array. It all seems to work but I also want to store the time that each value is added to the array (as part of the array) The code stores only unique values to a maximum of four.

```
 function getBand() {
     $band_name=$_GET['band_name'];
     return $band_name;
 }

$pages=$_SESSION['pages'];
if(in_array($_GET['band_name'], $pages)) {
    echo"Already in Array";
} else {        
    if (empty($_SESSION['pages']))
        $_SESSION['pages'] = array();

    $_SESSION['pages'][] = getBand();
    $_SESSION['pages'] = array_slice($_SESSION['pages'], -4);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `time ()` to get the time.
And store that in the desired array.

```
array_push ($array, time ());
```

Since you're talking about "the time they are added to the array" it could be that you mean microseconds which in that case use `microtime ()`

Note that **both functions don't return a formatted timestamp**, instead they return an integer.

More on `time ()` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)

More on `microtime ()` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php)

Comment: Excuse my complete ignorance but where in my code would I add the array_push?

Comment: You don't specifically need to use `array_push()` but that function does add it to the array, you should add the time to the array exactly there where you need it. You can always read up about `array_push()` [over here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

Comment: Just to be sure I made [this gist](https://gist.github.com/bobdesaunois/fc4bf3e2932caf6e50bf) demonstrating the use of `array_push ()`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this could do the work:

```
$test = "Metallica";
$test2 = "The Black Keys";

$arr['pages'][$test] = $test;
$arr['pages'][$test] = date("D M d, Y G:i");

$arr['pages'][$test2] = $test;
$arr['pages'][$test2] = date("D M d, Y G:i");


echo '<pre>'.print_r($arr, true).'</pre>';
```

For date format you can see - http://php.net/manual/bg/function.date.php

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
class SessionManager
{
    protected static $pages = null;
    protected static $maxPages = 4;

    public function __construct($session) {
        self::$pages = $session['pages'];
    }

    public static function addPage($pageName) {
        self::$pages[$pageName] = array(
            'name' => $pageName,
            'created' => date('Y-m-d h:i:s')
        );
        self::$pages = array_slice(self::$pages, -1 * $maxPages);
    }

    public static function writeSession(&$session) {
        $session['pages'] = self::$pages;
    }

    public static function getPages() {
        return self::$pages;
    }
}

session_start();
$session = new SessionManager($_SESSION);
$session->addPage($_GET['band_name']);
$session->writeSession($_SESSION);

print_pre($session->getPages());
```